# Ayuda con error en un ciclo for para obtener un valor de un array

Tags: python, array, loops

yo tengo un array:

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

y yo quiero que con un ciclo for imprima por pantalla solo 2 y 5, para eso hice:

```
for i in array:
    print(array[i][1])
```

pero entonces me da el siguiente error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integer or slices, not list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas la sintaxis `for variable in iterable:`, la `variable` va tomando los valores del iterable, no de sus índices como supones en tu código.

Es decir, en la primera iteración de tu bucle, la `i` tomará el valor del primer elemento que tenga la lista. Y ese elemento es a su vez otra lista (`[1,2,3]`). En la segunda iteración `i` contendrá el siguiente elemento, que es otra lista.

Teniendo en cuenta que en cada iteración (y en tu caso) la variable contiene una fila de tu array, sería mejor llamar `fila` a esa variable, en lugar de `i`. De este modo el código queda más legible:

```py
for fila in array:
    print(fila[1])
```

Otra opción que tienes es iterar por los índices en lugar de los valores. Esto es lo que suele hacerse en otros lenguajes como C. El código es más similar a lo que tú intentabas, pero es menos *pythónico*. Para poder hacerlo necesitas una lista de índices y típicamente se usa la función `range()` para construir una. Así:

```py
for i in range(len(array)):
    print(array[i][1])
```

**Nota**. El error que te daba python tiene todo el sentido, ya que en tu código, en la expresión `array[i][1]`, la `i` que estabas poniendo dentro de los corchetes era otra lista y no un entero. De ahí que te diga "*list indices must be integer or slices, not list*".